# How to take up all available space

Tags: html, space, css

I want `#x` to take up all available space. How do I do this?
[image]

(P.S. sorry for the mspaint)

Comment: Don't be sorry. It is awesome! :-)

Comment: Try "overflow:hidden" for the #x

Comment: Do other elements have fixed dimensions? If yes, it's just a matter of doing your math ;)

Comment: Can you post the CSS for elements `#contentwrapper`, `#a` and `#rw`?

Comment: No, they don't have fixed dimensions and there's no overflow either.

Comment: @Cristy there's no style applied to any of them, just the `display`'s, which I've labelled on this draft picture.

Comment: @Dunno I tried doing math stuff with JavaScript, but there must be a **nice** solution as well. This is a returning problem for me.

Comment: @Rápli András Ah, I see what you mean. I'm afraid there's no "nice", pure-css and automatic solution to this that's why I usually rely on fixed dimensions... anyway +1 to your question ;)

Comment: The never ending quest in the CSS world, how to make CSS vertically-aware?! it is true, there is no other way but js calculation, or fixed dimensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776367/css-making-a-div-consume-all-available-space  OR  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443983/make-a-div-take-up-all-available-vertical-space

Comment: What sort of content will be in #x? Is #x going to have variable amounts of content depending on its height? Or is it something simpler? If the former, you need JS; if the latter, there might be some CSS tricks to at least make it *look* like #x fills the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/bAJpz/4/

CSS

```
 #contentwrapper {
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #a, #rw, #x {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    #a {
        border: #ED1C24 3px solid;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #rw {
        display: inline-block;
        border: #FF7F27 3px solid;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50%;
    }
    #x {
        border: #7092BE 3px solid;
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: I think your link was wrong. Here's a forked fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/23MS4/](http://jsfiddle.net/23MS4/)

Comment: Who said I wanted `50%` height?

Answer (score 0):

I create one eample for you in [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HduVQ/)
use:

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Your fiddle is wrong. Even if you have thought of `overflow:hidden;` that wont work either. I can't simply make the div larger than it should be and make the overflow hidden because the parent div (`contentwrapper`) has no fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

If u are interested in using % use the following code , else u will have to find the width and height using firebug

```
   #contentwrapper {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 600px;
   }
  #a, #rw, #x {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
  }
  #a {
   border: 3px solid #ED1C24;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   height: 99%;
   width: 200px;
   }
  #rw {
    border: 3px solid #FF7F27;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   height: 70%;
   width: 388px;
  }
  #x {
     border: 3px solid #7092BE;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 27%;
    width: 388px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your image, you require to #x to use the complete height so define the height of #x. Defining the height of each block seperately in pixels (px) or Percentage (%) should resolve your concern.

Comment: There are textual content (sometimes more, sometimes less) in the other two divs, meaning I don't know their heights, it can only be queried using JavaScript. I put up the question to know if there was an easier (css) solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### You want `table`, not `inline-block`

Whenever you want some element to take up **available space**, you should consider `display: table` as your last resort. `inline-block` and `block` elements are useful when dealing with contents that are inside them, but are pretty limited in what they can do in terms of space of its parent container. Elements inside a `table` naturally fill up available space, making them much easier to work with when trying to achieve some design goals.

You will need a lot of wrappers for this. Let's go through them one by one.

#### #contentwrapper

We first make `#contentwrapper` a table and give it 2 cells to create the left and right columns. The left column is where `#a` is.

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#contentwrapper {
    display: table;
}

#a {
    display: table-cell;
}

#b {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[image]

#### #bcontentwrapper

Now we move on to the right column. Create another table called `#bcontentwrapper` under `#b`. Inside this table we will need 2 rows, each containing 1 cell, to construct `#rw` and `#x`.

We give `#rwwrapper` a height of `0` and `#xwrapper` a height of `100%` so that `#rw`'s height would depend on its content and `#x` will always take up the **remaining height** of the table.

If you are wondering, setting the height to `0` will not make the row collapse into a horizontal line since the row height has to be [at least the height required by its cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout), provided you have some content inside. And because rows and cells cannot overflow a table, a row with a positive height plus a row with a `100%` height can't actually exceed `100%`. The second row is forced to take whatever height is left by the first, giving us just what we need.

```
<div id="bcontentwrapper">
    <div id="rwwrapper">
        <div id="rw"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="xwrapper">
        <div id="x"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#bcontentwrapper {
    display: table;
}

#rwwrapper {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}

#rw {
    display: table-cell;
}

#xwrapper {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

#x {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[image]

#### Put them together

We put these 2 tables together and see how it looks.

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b">
        <div id="bcontentwrapper">
            <div id="rwwrapper">
                <div id="rw"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="xwrapper">
                <div id="x"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Ooops, this looks exactly like the problem we begin with. Are we back to square one?

Don't worry, there is one last trick left. Remember that we want `#x` to take up the available height? Naturally, you will want to give the table `#bcontentwrapper` a `100%` height so it will fill the entire cell of `#b`, and thus `#x` can take whatever is left inside this table.

But this is not quite enough. `#b` will try adjust its height to accommodate its content instead of taking the same height as `#a`. If the content in `#b` is shorter than that in `#a`, `#b` will be shorter than `#a`, leaving the space outside and there will be no available space for `#x` to consume.

To fix this we give `#b` a height of `0`. This is to replace the default height of `auto`, which causes it to take the minimum height required by its contents instead of the height of the row it is in (the implicit row for `#a` and `#b`). And since the row height has to be at least the height required by its cells, the `0` here allows `#b` to take as much height as it needs and keeps the heights of `#a` and `#b` in sync.

```css
#b {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 0;
}

#bcontentwrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
```

With everything done, `#x` can finally take up the available space it has always wanted to.

[image]

#### Demo

[Here is an interactive demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N3M4K/) of the all the things we have discussed so far. The main elements are made `contenteditable` so you can change the contents and see how the layout adjusts itself.

#### Caveat

The above solution only works on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. To make this work on IE, sigh, you need to use a `<table>`.

```
<table id="contentwrapper">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="a" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td id="rw"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="x"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Click here for the `<table>` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CNYP/). It's ugly, but IE has always been the exception. So whatever.